# Saving unknown number from the call log to my application

Tags: android, android-contacts

Tell me, please, is it possible to save the incoming call number (not yet saved in the contact list) from the standard list of "all calls" to my application ?
If so, how I can do this?
I would be grateful for any information on the topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the `CallLog` DB, see here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

For example:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE,
            null,
            CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
```

Will get you a cursor for all incoming calls, ordered by date.